# goroutines/channel - not exiting w/o ctlr-c

Tags: go

Please consider the following go code, which I wrote to scan a  TCP port (os.Arg[2]) of hostnames from a given filename (os.Arg[1]). It reads each hostname, tries to connect. If the connect failed, it would append the failed hostname to outfile.

```
package main

import(
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "log"
    "bufio"
    "time"
    "net"
)


func main(){
    argc := len(os.Args)
    if argc < 3 {
        fmt.Printf("Invalid usage")
        log.Fatal("Invalid usage")

    }

    stamp := time.Now().UnixNano()
    outfile := fmt.Sprintf("%s%d.txt", "/tmp/port_check", stamp)

    filename := os.Args[1] 
    file, err := os.Open(filename)
    checkerr(err)

    f, err := os.OpenFile(outfile, os.O_APPEND|os.O_CREATE|os.O_WRONLY, 0644)
    checkerr(err)
    defer f.Close()

    port := os.Args[2]

    channel := make(chan string,17)
    fscanner := bufio.NewScanner(file)
    for fscanner.Scan(){
        _line := fscanner.Text()
        go check_sender(_line,port,f,channel)
    }

        _count := 0
        for out := range channel{
            fmt.Println("_count is:", _count, out)
            _count += 1
        }

        close(channel)
}


func checkerr(err error){
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}

func check_sender(sender string, port string, f *os.File, channel chan string){
    address_string := fmt.Sprintf("%s:%s", sender, port)
    _, err := net.DialTimeout("tcp", address_string,4 * time.Second)
    if err != nil {
        write_this := fmt.Sprintf("%s\n", sender)
        f.WriteString(write_this)
    }
    channel <- sender
}
```

Generate some content for it operate on:

```
 $ for i in `seq 1 5`; do  echo "someblog$RANDOM$RANDOM.blogspot.com"; done  > /tmp/meh.txt
```

And when run  as:

```
$ go run port_scan.go /tmp/meh.txt 80
_count is: 0 someblog50063432.blogspot.com
_count is: 1 someblog922816893.blogspot.com
_count is: 2 someblog622823698.blogspot.com
_count is: 3 someblog1074223783.blogspot.com
_count is: 4 someblog1876411881.blogspot.com
^Csignal: interrupt < ----------------------- this
```

It hangs after the last hostname, and does not exit until a ctlr-c is sent.

I would like it to exit by itself, what am I doing wrong here?

**update 1:**

```
    channel := make(chan string,17)
    fscanner := bufio.NewScanner(file)
+   spin := 0
    for fscanner.Scan(){
        _line := fscanner.Text()
        go check_sender(_line,port,f,channel)
+       spin += 1
    }

        _count := 0
        for out := range channel{
            fmt.Println("_count is:", _count, out)
            _count += 1
+           if _count == spin {
+               close(channel)
+           }
        }

-       close(channel)
 }
```

Comment: Thanks. Pls see update 1 above -  counting how many threads you fork, and after we reap the same count,  `close(channel)` seems to work. Question though, is doing all this by hand required, or is there an automatic method to handle situations like this?

Comment: @struggling_learner: it is hard to give recommendation since your original design intentions are not really known. Specifically you create a channel of size 17. My guess that this you want to use this to restrict the number of parallel connection attempts. But you are actually not doing this since you first connect and then push something into the channel, i.e. all what you limit is how much results you can return in parallel and not how much connections you do in parallel.

Comment: @Steffen, How do I then restrict the number of parallel connection attempts? This was my intention, and I thought I was doing this..

Comment: @struggling_learner: see for example [Limiting Concurrency in Go](http://jmoiron.net/blog/limiting-concurrency-in-go/).